Python .py into exe and as administrator
I made a python text game ages ago that was really complicated but I wanted to send it to some friends. I tried to convert it into a exe using pyinstaller but I had a lot of issues. It wouldn't let me convert the file as my antivirus was going nuts, I use Total AV but even when I disabled it it didn't let me convert my file. I was just going to send it and ask them to install python, but they had trouble launching the game, as it would require administrator permissions to write files. I'm not very good at coding or python so I had a lot of issues.
I'd love some help to fix this issue, I've included a link to the game file below as it is extremely big
Any help converting this to an exe or help with opening as administrator would be much appreciated
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MxYZMWKPKPw75w-x9OnyyI9Cluleg6CS?usp=sharing

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You shouldn't need Administrator privileges to run a Python console application. I've previously encountered false positives with PyInstaller, but not recently. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], see [ask] for more information or take the [tour].
